# How to fix long titles for divs

Tags: css, html, fonts

The title's a bit tricky lol sorry for that .. can't think of more appropriate one.

So I' working on this website : 
http://www.whybaguio.com/php/profile/businessprofile.php?id=1603

I'm having a little problem... If the Business name's too long like this one: 
http://www.whybaguio.com/php/profile/businessprofile.php?id=164 The category and the Facebook like button disappears and probably goes down...

Like maybe changing the font size automatically or something?

Answer (score 0):

Give `#cat2b` tag `display:block`(or use `div` instead of `span`) and remove all `br` tags from `#buscontent` div.

---

Not sure how your page layout is happening. anyway to avoid future bugs give `overflow-x: auto` and `height: 15px` to `#cat2b`. (I don't recommend this but your layout really need fix from beginning I think)

Comment: I think so too :( having problems with the positioning everytime something's too long or whatevs :(( Super frustrating.

Comment: @discofuse It seems you are beginner. If so, then I can say only one thing **redesign** :(. and don't use margins to layout the page like you did here. Use as much as divs and nested divs to make it look better. that's all I can say. Go through some tuturials first.